# function for finding lowest available

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create function which will return for my script lowest available id of current user. For example, let's say, there's user with id 25, so he will be able to enter 10addresses, numbered from 250 to 259. So i created this function:

```
protected function checkAvailIDforAddress($id)
{

    $min = $id*10;
    $max = $id*10 + 9;

    $checkAvailID = $this->_dbconnection->prepare
            ('SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM user_address WHERE user_id BETWEEN :min AND :max');

    $checkAvailID->bindParam(':min', $min);
    $checkAvailID->bindParam(':max', $max);

    $checkAvailID->execute();

    $row = $checkAvailID->fetch();

    if ($row[0] == 0) throw new Exception('Error');

    $AvailID = $row[0] + 1;

    return $AvailID;


}
```

I thought, that this function will be good, but then i tested it and i found out, that if user put into db 3addresses, and then deleted 2nd, the function still return max. value, so entry will be added as 4th and 2nd will be unset.

Then I altered the question with foreach loop, and in every loop I made query to db to check, whether is certain id unset, but i think that this query is really uneffective. So my question is: is there some query to db which will return first available id between two values?

Comment: You should create other table to store the relation between them. Then you can simple use `JOIN`.

Comment: generally you should NOT try to reuse old keys - nor should the actual value matter. Use a SEQUENCE and just take the next available value.

Comment: Use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id field or use some other form of non-sequential IDs (GUIDs) if they make sense. You are asking for problems trying to manage IDs yourself especially if you scale horizontally and have two machines calculate the same ID as "valid."

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say this, but your question makes absolutely no sense.

I will point out that if you are looking for the LOWEST possible user_id, using SELECT MAX(user_id) is the opposite of what you want...

If you want a range, use SELECT MIN(user_id) as min, MAX(user_id) as max ....

```
'SELECT MIN(user_id) as min, MAX(user_id) as max FROM user_address WHERE user_id BETWEEN :min AND :max'
```

If your results, you will now have a 'min' and 'max' value that you can use to determine a range of available ID's?

Comment: when i found max entered into db and increase it by one, the result will be lowest available id...

Comment: But your program does not account for shifting ID numbers which is a flaw in your DB design. Your dilemma stands. IE

Insert with ID 255
Insert with ID 256
DELETE with ID 255

256 still exists which is the highest number. If you use the min/max range you will inherently know what numbers are available.

If I select between 250 and 259 and my only result is the row with an ID of 256, then I now know that I could use 250-255, and 257-259.

Don't down my answer because you don't understand the math.

Comment: It's not me who downvote it, because I'm thankfull for any help, and now I found your solution quite good, but i thoght about what people said in comments and remake the code. But thanks, I will upvote you :)